# What letter with the latin base of a has the most diacritics

Tags: accents

I'm making a fantasy world and I would like to know what letter with the base of 'a' has the most diacritic marks on it. The largest I can find is 'ą̄́', but I'm almost sure there is one with more diacritic marks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here. However, some fonts allow you to stack as many diacritics as you want. However, results are far from being aesthetic.

Comment: ạ̣̣̣̣̣̈̈̈̈̈̈ perhaps?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic here ...

Comment: Since the question has an answer, it would probably be better to leave the question as it was, and let it fade from history.  As things are now, you've made the answer not make much sense, because it's responding to nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: it depends on the font if you consider combining marks. For instance, with Charis SIL we can stack as many diacritics as we want.

```
%Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{standalone}
%%% For older distributions
%\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
%%% Sorry for my unorthodox LaTeX3
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\replicate\prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
a\replicate{7}{\char"302\relax}
a\replicate{10}{\char"30A\relax}
a\char"300\char"301\char"302\char"303\char"304\char"30B\relax
\end{document}
```

[image]